# Can a Mac's part number be determined with a Terminal Command?

Tags: macbook-pro, command-line

I need to determine the Apple Part Number 'MXXXXXLL/A' and do not have the original packaging.  Is there a way to do this from command line?

I don't need model #, I specifically need the part #.  Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried in the System Information app?

Answer (score 5):

Apple Order Numbers -- which also are referred to as Model Numbers, Part Numbers, or Marketing Numbers.

Unfortunately, Order Numbers cannot be found on the hardware itself nor can they be found in the "About This Mac" section of OS X, and this is the primary limitation of the identifier.

Nor can it be determined using Terminal.

---

Open About this Mac  and copy the serial number from there.

Paste that number in the search box on the [Look up web page](https://everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/?search_keywords=C02W92Z5J1WL&g-recaptcha-response=03AMGVjXiak1nFuulw5dMm2KC1NEVKu_Q0qWhS3uKeySk5XraQTIzsIh-xxZ63OgZP_aaNRixhIoOylkw8mYJcHacrwWvuTthmSbPwES0onf4VYCetvGuBJ0eG4N4g85OYEYLq-5GMTDQ2OIxbj_Jd3uVq0b8KbU-Fq1R3BfuqlJL-ck_3CVgAhf2XAa8B4xrMi_yfuY93ML4Lp6K9bML0tcxxouZ_6WRPKoWqJw8imUOeMuQKQPprJ75xVZc-jb6rBdi54vxH1mWU103aNyo7HHCTVRVkdJUwj9DnBdh64txlbqwY90BdziD-yd59AJ5bmY8OR5T25zNJnPxlDzQLT8v3nNJMRIAWhg)

It will show you the "Order Number"  as example  `Order     MQXXXLL/A`

Comment: Saw that earlier. As long as you know the year and quarter your Mac was purchased in, you can figure out the rest from the model on the bottom of your Mac (for example mine is A1278). Or you can use the serial number instead of model.

Comment: @JesseP. correct, you can do it that way as well